# blockchain.raw download for the testnet?

Tags: monerod, testnet

I've started running monerod connected to the testnet but the sync is extremely slow. Is there a download for the testnet blockchain as per the regular blockchain (https://downloads.getmonero.org/blockchain.raw)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Spam for stupid length check not wanting short answers.